Associate rows with time values to night with unique identifier
I have the data frame (moon_data) below with moon altitude and illumination for each hour of the days.
                   date     altitude     illum
9   2020-08-31 05:30:00  -0.29518673 0.9676100
10  2020-08-31 06:30:00  -0.26451042 0.9690620
11  2020-08-31 07:30:00  -0.19938593 0.9704781
12  2020-08-31 08:30:00  -0.10514524 0.9718584
13  2020-08-31 09:30:00   0.01137494 0.9732028

I created a second data frame (night_info) with the start time and end time of each night, and the column "night_of" which is basically a unique ID for each night, as follow:
      night_of         night_start           night_end
1   2020-08-30 2020-08-30 19:43:00 2020-08-31 06:25:06
2   2020-08-31 2020-08-31 19:41:03 2020-09-01 06:26:24
3   2020-09-01 2020-09-01 19:39:06 2020-09-02 06:27:43

I would like to average illumination per night from sunset to sunrise and I am drawing a blank...
I created a time interval for each night and was hoping to use it to associate each row in moon_data to the corresponding "night of", but I am not sure how to proceed.
In other words : If moon_data$date falls within one of the intervals of night_info, return corresponding "night_of".
Any help would be GREATLY appreciate!

I think you're looking for this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.16.2/topics/foverlaps

Sounds like you want to join on the matching date, ignoring the time elements of the timestamp. Once you do that, you can simply compare whether the timestamp is in the interval you care about (after night_start and before night_end).

Please share more data, so we have at least two days.
